# Oracle Grant then SYNONYM is there any other ways?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

To be able to let other schema to use the table it doesn't own, I normally

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE t TO otherUser 

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM t FOR t
```

the question is I always thought Oracle should automatically let the newUser SEE the table, if I grant select on it.

in reality, I have to create a synonym, other wise the new user can't select on it

I wander is there any other way? to let the other user see the table and perform select without create a synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wander is there any other way? to let the other user see the table and perform select without create a synonym?

Yes.

Without the synonym, the other users must specify the **SCHEMA_NAME** to refer the table in other schema.

```
SCHEMA.TABLE
```

---

A good point added by @Boneist. At times, you could avoid flooding the system with synonyms, and simply issue an alter session statement to set the current schema to the schema you wish to access the objects.

A good discussion [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:588045400346317188) in details on AskTom.

Comment: Or the user could issue `alter session set current schema = schemaname;`

Comment: @Boneist Yes, a good way to avoid synonyms and some less parsing without schema names. Added the same in the answer. Thanks

Comment: also apart from the table or view owner, who else can grant select on other schema/user?

Comment: @Boneist [Those Tahiti days ;-) LOL!](https://community.oracle.com/thread/666546)

Comment: @user5324782 The database owner always has the privilege to do so. Or if any user has been given the privilege to do so.

Comment: @LalitKumarB {looks mournful} aaah, tahiti.oracle.com, why have you forsaken us?! *{;-)